# 80s movie where the characters are taken over by an alien hive mind

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, horror

The characters ate some substance and then they were taken over by some alien hive mind. It brainwashes the whole town.  You could tell when they were possessed because they would say, “What difference does it make?”

I had thought it was the movie *The Stuff*, but it wasn't.  It was similar though. I do believe they got free in the end the children set them free somehow. I was like 5 years old watching the movie so I can’t remember too many other details.

Comment: Ate not are they eat something and it brain washes the whole town

Comment: Can you remember anything else about this? Do they get free in the end? What’s the overarching plot? Can you remember any specific scenes? If you do remember anything else you can [edit] your question to add that detail in.

Answer (score 1):

Might it be the 1987 film *The Curse* with Wil Wheaton?

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Curse_(1987_film)):

> a large meteorite crashes onto the property, emitting an eerie glow. Next morning, Alan Forbes, a physician who lives nearby, visits the crash-site, examining the meteorite which is a large sphere with a hard shell from which a noxious liquid oozes out. Before long, the object dissolves into glowing gelatinous liquid which seeps into the soil....

The substance begins to mutate crops and madden family members who consume it in the water they drink and the tainted food they eat.

Comment: Do they say *"What difference does it make?"* when they've been taken over?

Comment: The Curse is the second film version of H.P. Lovecraft's story "The Colour Out of Space", 1927.